# Mat-Chip-Grid is not assignable to Mat-Chip-Grid and Mat-Legacy-Chip-List

Tags: angular, angular-material

I get this above error. It looks like this is wrong [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid"

```
 <mat-chip-grid #chipGrid aria-label="Enter fruits">
          <mat-chip-row *ngFor="let lang of languages"
                        (removed)="remove(lang)"
                        [editable]="true"
                        (edited)="edit(lang, $event)"
                        [aria-description]="'press enter to edit ' + lang.name">
            {{lang.name}}
            <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + lang.name">
              <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </mat-chip-row>
          <input placeholder="New Lang..."
                 [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid"
                 [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                 [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                 (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"/>
        </mat-chip-grid>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: were you able to solve this? I have the same issue in Angular 16 and material v16

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for some reason, IDE imported legacy versions automatically

```
import { MatLegacyChipsModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-chips';
import { MatLegacyFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-form-field';
```

However non-legacy components need to be used.

For whoever will want to use Legacy, there is a solution.

Add in the component:

```
@ViewChild('chipGrid', { static: true }) chipGridLegacy!: MatChipGrid & MatLegacyChipList;
```

and use it for binding

```
[matChipInputFor]="chipGridLegacy"
```